# State data is not getting changed with ngRx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to display a component on the basis of the value in the store.

**login-component.html**

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="box" *ngIf="!isLoggedIn$ | async">
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <input [value]="username" (input)="username = $event.target.value" class="email">

    <input [value]="password" (input)="password = $event.target.value" class="password">

    <div class="btn" (click)="login()">Sign In</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**login-component.ts**

```
@Component ( {
  selector :'app-login' ,
  templateUrl :'./login.component.html',
  styleUrls :['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  username: string = 'username';
  password: string = 'password';
  isLoggedIn$ : Observable<boolean>;

  constructor (private store: Store<AppState> , private route: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit () {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.store.pipe(map(state=> state.auth.loggedIn));
  }

  login () {
    if (this.username === 'Iftekhar' && this.password === 'Sunny') {
      const user: User = {
        'id' :1 ,
        'name' :'Iftekhar'
      };
      this.store.dispatch ( new LoggedInAction ( {user} ) );
    }
  }
}
```

The login page will be displayed on the basis of the loggedIn value from the store. Here the flag is not been getting set in ngOnInit() method. 
Initially my store will be empty when the user goes to - localhost:4200.
Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong.

The entire code can be found here - https://github.com/training-session-101/Angular6

Answer (score 0):

try put parenthesis on async

```
<div class="box" *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn$ | async)">
```

Comment: using the parenthesis sets the value correctly when the app loads first time. But after i click on submit the value of isLoggedIn$ is not getting changed and thus the login page still remains there.